# Why even after applying stripslashes the extra slashes are not getting removed in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, backslash, stripslashes, smarty2

I'm using smarty template engine. In smarty code I've used stripslashes function to remove the extra slashes appearing in a string but the slashes are not getting removed. How shold I resolve this issue?

Following is the string and the code that I'm using to remove these slashes:

String :  `{assign var="brand" value="Lindeman's"}`

The code I written : `{$brand|stripslashes}`

The output I'm getting is : **Lindeman\\'s**

The output should actually be : **Lindeman's**

How should I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If desired output for you is `Lindeman's` and you set your string as:

```
{assign var="brand" value="Lindeman's"}
```

to display it, you should simply use:

```
{$brand}
```

You don't need to use any stripslashes here because you want to display the same string as you have inside your variable

**EDIT**

And even when I use

```
{$brand|stripslashes}
```

I get the exactly same output: `Lindeman's` so probably you do something wrong or your input string is different.

Comment: Actually I had viven you one example of single variable. In fact I'm applying stripslashes to each index element of an array using loop. SO I want to apply on each of the variable. At that tome I'm getting this issue.

Comment: @PHPLover So you must be doing something wrong. Without a code and input data and desired output it's hard to say because in the example you have everything works fine as expected

Comment: :Ok, I'll update my question for you withon 10 minutes.